# windows "zip folders" file encodings

Tags: windows, character-encoding, zip, filenames

which encodings do windows use when reading filenames from zip archive thru zip folders?

as far as I know
cyrillic is represented as cp866 and
central european - cp437

what about other?

- Portuguese
- Español (Spanish)
- Français (French)
- Polski (Polish)
- Türkçe (Turkish)
- Deutsch (German)
- Italiano (Italian)
- العربية (Arabic)
- Farsi
- ไทย (Thai)
- 中文 (Chinese)
- 日本語 (Japanese)
- 한국어 (Korean)
- Tiếng Việt (Vietnamese)

I think first seven of this are in cp437.
Chinese may be in Big5
But I know nothing about others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Apache Commons Compress Zip package documentation](http://commons.apache.org/compress/zip.html) it's the platforms default encoding.

> Windows' "compressed folder" feature doesn't recognize any flag or
>   extra field and creates archives using the platforms default encoding
>   - and expects archives to be in that encoding when reading them.